# Is this a correct sentence "你今天就不说多的话了"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, phrase-meaning

Usually you do talk much with me. But today I feel like there is something happened and I feel like that you don't talk much today. It is correct to say to you: "你今天就不说多的话了"?

The meaning to me: "You just don't talk much today".

Comment: Yes, the sentence is grammatically correct, except to make it better, you could add some metaphors and similes.

Comment: 你今天就不说多的话了(quite stilted) is slightly different from the meaning you intended. 你今天就没说多少话 is fit for that meaning.

Answer (score 2):

You could put it this way:

你今天很安静啊!
You're quiet today!

Maybe:
今天你话很少。

or

你今天不怎么说话。

Comment: If I want to use the word `speak` or `talk` and `just`  in the sentence. How can I say that?

Answer (score 2):

你今天就不说多的话了 sounds like a 祈使句, meaning 'please do not say anything else today'.

Pedroski's suggestion is great. What's more, to use the word 'speak' or 'talk', we can say:

- 你今天说话很少呢。
- 你今天咋没说几句话？

To add 'just' and mean 'You just don't talk much today', we can say:

- 你今天**根本**没说几句话。
- 你今天**本来就**说话很少。
- 你今天**本来就**没说几句话。
- 你今天**真的**没说啥。
- 你今天**真的**说话很少。
- 你今天**真的**没说几句话。

However, limited by my English capability, I am not sure about what 'just' really means in the sentence. Maybe there are alternative meanings?

Answer (score 1):

"你今天就不说多的话了"?

I'll modify it to be more listener-friendly (especially the native speakers).

為什麼你今天就不多说话了? = 怎麼你今天就不多说话了? In both, "话" can be eliminated.

One more - 怎麼你今天就不多囉唆了? 囉唆 means "speak/talk too much", usually in a continuous, non-stoppable manner on trivial things, or something the listener is not interested in. But you may use it when talking to your loved ones or close friends with a mild/loving tune, then it becomes an expression of love or closeness in a joking manner (調侃).

**Some equivalent sentences:**

All sentences below are identical but expressed in different manners/tunes.

1. PLain questioning, 你今天不太說話, 為什麼? or 為什麼你今天不太說話?
2. Double questions, 你今天怎麼不多話了? 為什麼?
3. Question follows comment, 你今天話說的很少啊! 為什麼?

Note, in sentences 2 & 3, "為什麼?" is unnecessary, as it is implied in the leading sentence.